# jquery replacing text in one tag

Tags: jquery

so as you see in the picture there is some text into li tag. Text is generating by wordpress theme panel admin. And what I am trying to do is to replace part of the text in the same tag. So I want to have just: Powierzchnia w m²: 93.5

[image]

I made some jquery script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    let str = document.getElementById("class-20").innerHTML;
    let first = str.split("&nbsp;")[0];
    first = first.substr(8);

    //let foundin3 = str.indexOf(":");
    let foundin4 = $('*:contains(":")');

    $( str ).insertAfter( foundin4 );       
    //foundin4.after(first)
    //foundin4.appendChild(first);
});
```

But it doesn't give expected results.
So, first question, is it correct to give as arguments to .insertAfter variables (7 line of actual code) as I did instead of html tags/classes?

Right now, after running this in dev tools console I have:

[image]

Secondly, maybe you see potential syntax error, what is causing error.

Comment: The error is because you are using str as selector. Which is not valid.

Comment: ok, are you see solution to this by using .insertAfter,

Comment: I have idea to use .replaceWith instead

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use queryselector first and then change the text. It would be something like this:
   var changeIt =  document.querySelector('li#class-20');
   $(changeIt).innerHtml("put your text here");

Comment: This one is better:
document.querySelector("li#class-20").innerHTML = "Powierzchnia w m²: 93.5";

Comment: This solution only refers if you know each time what text value is. And the whole problem is to change places of two parts of text, which is generating by panel admin. So right approach is to solve this in more general way. Not changing the text, but swapping parts of String. Your answear is static and dynamic one is needed on this case.

Answer (score 0):

I played with the content of this String, which also lead me to the right solution:

```
let str = document.getElementById("class-20").innerHTML;
let first = str.split("&nbsp;")[0];
first = first.substr(8);
let second = str.split("&nbsp;")[1];

let third = second + first;
$("#class-20").replaceWith(third);
```